# Co-coordinator pressure using IN query on single partition key with 9000 records 4MB size per partiton size

Tags: cassandra

I have 1000 partitions per table and `cust_id` is partition key and `bucket_id` and `timestamp` are the cluster keys.
Every hour one `bucket_id` and `timestamp` entry are recorded per cust_id.

- Each day 24 * 1 = 24 rows will be recorded per partiton.
- One year approx 9000 records per partion.
- Partion size is 4MB approx.

---> 20 nodes Cassandra cluster single DC and RF=3

I want to select random five buckets for last 90 days data using IN query.

```
select cust_id,bucket_id,timestamp from customer_data where 
   cust_id='tlCXP5oB0cE2ryjgvvCyC52thm9Q11KJsEWe' and 
   bucket_id IN (0,2,5,7,8)  
   and timestamp >='2020-03-01 00:00:00' and 
   timestamp <='2020-06-01 00:00:00';
```

Please confirm, does this approach cause any issues with coordinator pressure and query timeouts?
How much data can a coordinator bear and return data without any issue?

How (internally) does an IN query scan the records on Cassandra?  Please provide any detailed explanation.

If I run same kind of query for 10 Mil customers, does this affect coordinator pressure?  Does it increase the chances to get a read timeout error?

Answer (score 1):

It's could be hard to get definitive yes/no answer to these questions - there are some unknowns in them. For example, what version of Cassandra, how much memory is allocated for instance, what disks are used for data, what compaction strategy is used for a table, what consistency level do you use for reading the data, etc.

Overall, on the recent versions of Cassandra and when using SSDs, I won't expect problems with that, until you have hundreds of items in the `IN` list, especially if you're using consistency level `LOCAL_ONE` and prepared queries - all drivers use token-aware load balancing policy by default, and will route request to the node that holds the data, so it will be both coordinator & data node.  Use of other consistency levels would put more pressure to the coordinating node, but it still should work quite good.  The problem with read timeouts could start if you use HDDs, and overall incorrectly size the cluster.

Regarding the 10Mil customers - in your query you're doing select by partition key, so query is usually sent to a replica directly (if you use prepared statements).  To avoid problems you shouldn't do `IN` for partition key column (`cust_id` in your case) - if you do queries for individual customers, driver will spread queries over the whole cluster & you'll avoid increased pressure on coordinator nodes.

But as usual, you need to test your table schema & cluster setup to prove this. I would recommend to use [NoSQLBench](http://docs.nosqlbench.io) - benchmark/load testing tool that was recently open sourced by DataStax - it was built for quick load testing of cluster and checking data models, and incorporates a lot of knowledge in area of performance testing.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to ask one question per question.

Regarding the how much a coordinator node can handle, Alex is correct in that there are several factors which contribute to that.

- Size of the result set.
- Heap/RAM available on the coordinator node.
- Network consistency between nodes.
- Storage config (spinning, SSD, NFS, etc).

Coordinator pressure will vary widely based on these parameters.  My advice, is to leave all timeout threshold settings at their defaults.  They are there to protect your nodes from becoming overwhelmed.  Timeouts are Cassandra's way of helping you figure out how much it can handle.

> How (internally) does an IN query scan the records on Cassandra? Please provide any detailed explanation.

Based on your description, the primary key definition should look like this:

```
PRIMARY KEY ((cust_id),bucket_id,timestamp)
```

The data will be stored on disk by partition, and sorted by the cluster keys, similar to this (assuming ascending order on `bucket_id` and descending order on `timestamp`:

```
cust_id                                bucket_id timestamp
'tlCXP5oB0cE2ryjgvvCyC52thm9Q11KJsEWe' 0         2020-03-02 04:00:00
                                                 2020-03-01 22:00:00
                                       1         2020-03-27 16:00:00
                                       2         2020-04-22 05:00:00
                                                 2020-04-01 17:00:00
                                                 2020-03-05 22:00:00
                                       3         2020-04-27 19:00:00
                                       4         2020-03-27 17:00:00
                                       5         2020-04-12 08:00:00
                                                 2020-04-01 12:00:00
```

Cassandra reads through the SSTable files in that order.  It's important to remember that Cassandra reads *sequentially* off disk.  When queries force it to perform *random* reads, that's when things may start to get a little slow.  The read path has structures like partition offsets and bloom filters which help it figure out which files (and where inside them) have the data.  But within a partition, it will need to scan clustering keys and figure out what to skip and what to return.

Depending on how many updates these rows have taken, it's important to remember that the requested data may stretch across multiple files.  Reading one file is faster than reading more than one.

At the very least, you're forcing it to stay on one node by specifying the partition key.  But you'll have to test how much a coordinator can return before causing problems.  In general, I wouldn't specify double digits of items in an `IN` clause.

In terms of optimizing file access, Jon Haddad (now of Apple) has a *great* article on this: [Apache Cassandra Performance Tuning - Compression with Mixed Workloads](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2018/08/08/compression_performance.html)  It focuses mainly on the table compression settings (namely `chunk_length_in_kb`) and has some great tips on how to improve data access performance.  Specifically, the section "How Data is Read" is of particular interest:

> We pull chunks out of SSTables, decompress them, and return them to the client....During the read path, the entire chunk must be read and decompressed. We’re not able to selectively read only the bytes we need. The impact of this is that if we are using 4K chunks, we can get away with only reading 4K off disk. If we use 256KB chunks, we have to read the entire 256K.

The point of this ^ relevant to your question, is that by skipping around (using `IN`) the coordinator will likely read data that it won't be returning.

Comment: Cassandra Version 3.11.4
CPU ---------> 8 core cpu
RAM --------> 32 GB RAM
HEAP ------> XMS : 8GB   XMX:16GB
PARTION SIZE: 4MB  
 HARD DISK --> NORMAL HDD.   We are not using SSD disks
COMPACTION STRATEGY ---> SIZE TIERED
OS ---> CENTS OS 7.3
CONSISTENCY LVEL ---> LOCAL_QUORUM

Comment: @sateesh There isn't a formula to compute coordinator performance based on what you just provided.  You'll need to run your own tests to figure out the tolernances.